# Why this onClick function is not being created properly using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am creating new buttons when calling a JS function but I think there is something wrong with the way I am stringifying the object inside the onclick event handler which I am passing as parameter:

```
...
var edit_button = '<button type="button" id="buttons" onclick="edit_admin_request(this,\'' + JSON.stringify(edit_admin_object) + '\')" name="edit_admin">Edit</button>';
var rowNode = myTable.row(window.rowindex).data([edit_button]).draw();
...
```

when this button is created, when I try to click on it, it doesn't call the `edit_admin_request(this_,data_)` function at all.

If I try to pass a simple string instead of a stringified object `onclick="edit_admin_request(this,\'' + ["a string inside if an array"] + '\')"` , this works, I am able to call the `edit_admin_request(this_,data_)` function.

I dont understand why is this happening?!

UPDATE:
here is the row where I display the button (note: I am using dynamic table, so this row is inside a foreach loop):

```
 <td>
   <div id="edit_button_row" class="edit_button_row">
     <button type="button" class="edit_admin" id="buttons" onclick='edit_admin_request(this,<?php echo json_encode($user); ?>)' name="edit_admin">Edit</button>
   </div>
 </td>
```

Comment: It's most likely being broken due to the double quotes in the JSON interfering with those in the HTML attributes. This is partly why inline event handlers are a bad idea. I'd strongly suggest you change the logic to use unobtrusive event handlers instead. Research the `addEventListener()` method.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan at this moment I just wanna fix the one I am using. Howwould you fix that string syntax?

Comment: You are using some kind of framework. What is it and show some more code. A [mcve] would be great

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. Please ask: How do I insert a button in a datatable row and have that button call a function with an object I have somewhere

Comment: You need to explain to us if the object you stringify is the same for all rows. If yes, don't pass it. you will never be able to have enought types of quotes to insert it into an attribute

Comment: @mplungjan same data you mean? Of course its not the same data, that's why I am adding  a button for each row. Each row has different data. I already explained this. When page is loaded I am displaying a datatable with some rows. Then I decide to Edit one of the rows, but when the row data have been edited, I OF COURSE need to modify the object in the onclick function.

Comment: So why not store the data in the table row as a hidden cell? You can access it using relative access from the button

Comment: @mplungjan I just thought about it actually. But how can I then update the row that I want to in JS?

Comment: `$("#tableID").on("click",".edit-admin",function(e) { const $row = $(this).closest("tr"); const data = JSON.parse($row.find(".datacell").text()) })` assuming you MUST save some data somewhere for each row

Comment: @mplungjan what should `.datacell` exactly be? Do I need to give an ID to <td> ?

Comment: No. class="datacell" and make `.datacell { display:none }` in css

Comment: @mplungjan but what  exactly do you mean by datacell? is it the <td> tag?

Comment: Yes. `<td class="datacell">{"some":"json","you":"need","to":"parse"}</td>`

Comment: @mplungjan my current rows look like this when page loaded, I am displaying PHP data on them: `<td class="datacell"><b><?php echo $user["name"]; ?> </b></td>`

Comment: So username is the only thing you need to pass to the edit_admin function()?
then no need to parse: `<td class="datacell"><?php echo $user["name"]; ?></td>` - it is now just a string that is readable with `$row.find(".datacell").text()` without HTML and parsing

Comment: @mplungjan sorry, just made it work. didn't understand it before. The only issue now is that the text does not have proper formatting, it has too much spaces between `$row.find(".datacell").text()` ,so how can I actually properly format it?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean `$row.find(".datacell").text()` does not have any spaces

Comment: @mplungjan when I print this `const data =  $row.find(".datacell").text()` instead of printing `"Name Surname"` it prints something like this  `"    NAME Surname               " ` with a lot of space between text. Maybe because its PHP data?! Remember, I need to display these data of each cell somewhere (in a Modal) and then edit them.

Comment: Possibly. Then just add trim: `$row.find(".datacell").text().trim()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading the comments I will post my findings as an answer

1. Add the user name in a hidden cell to make sure any quotes or special characters do not mess up the passing of the data.
   `<td class="datacell"><?php echo $user["name"]; ?></td>`
2. Give the cell a class
3. Add the button, giving it a class
4. Add to the page this code, where tableID is the id of the table or the tbody

---

```
$("#tableID").on("click",".edit-admin",function(e) { 
  const $row = $(this).closest("tr"); 
  const data = $row.find(".datacell").text().trim(); // in case the PHP addes spaces
  edit_admin_request(this,data);
});
```

Comment: any idea why I cant access hidden columns? I am hiding them like this: `{"targets": [6, 7, 8], "visible": false }`

Comment: I have not used datatables